# Why do I see apache's 404 and not Django custom 404?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, http-status-code-404

On my local django runserver I created a custom `templates/404.html`, and this works no problem. However in production with `apache` this custom `404.html` is no longer shown (even with `DEBUG=False`).

I just get a white page with

```
Not Found

The requested URL /blahblah was not found on this server.
```

I don't believe that this isn't even the django default, but rather something to do with apache.

How do I tell apache to let django handle the 404s?

Comment: Have you compared the Apache configuration files in your dev and production servers?

Comment: The dev server that I mention is the django runserver not apache. Updated my OP.

Comment: You need to set up Apache so that error pages are served by Django. You should be able to find guides to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After all that I simply had forgotten to set the needed permissions for the template on the production server(I'm running `mod_wsgi` in daemon mode as 'djangoUser'), so I needed

```
dr-x------  djangoUser djangoUser  templates
dr-------   djangoUser djangoUser  templates/404.html
```

d'oh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the error404 handler in your Django app (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, the default 404 handler fits my needs, and django knows where to find my custom "404.html" template in my project (as shown in the local runserver).